# how can I publish web whit my database?

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio, publish

I deploy a web in asp.net whit visual studio 2105 and my I deploy my database in SQL Server 2012. I want to publish my web as my database put in app_data folder near my web. Can i do this?
In addition i can't add my database local in app_data folder near my website because of version error in visual studio.net 2015.